# Passing values through setter in super constructor

Tags: java, chaining

I have the following problem.
I have a Base class with a constructor taking three values upon initialization:

```
public Base(String a, int b, int c){
         this.setA(a);
         this.b = b;
         this.setC(c); }
```

After that I want to validate through a setter in the child class the value of 'b'. I am trying to pass my check like so :

```
private final int c = 5000;

public Child(String a, int b){
super(a, this.setB(b), 5000)
}
```

but I get the following message

> "Cannot reference 'this' before supertype constructor has been called"

.
Can I try to use it like so:

private final int c = 5000;

```
    public Child(String a, int b){
    super(a, b, 5000)
    this.setB(b);
    }
```

or do i have to use a totaly different approach?

Comment: Normally, a setter returns `void` (i.e. nothinig) (or the instance itself for method chaining, but that's another topic). So a call to `setB(...)` would evaluate to no value, and we cannot pass "no value" as parameter to a method.

Comment: Also, 'this' wont be available untill 'super' call is completed. So you would probably have to go with your second approach.